# System 'bash -ic' stuck when I hit ctrl+c

Tags: ruby, bash, shell

When i try `system 'bash -ic'`, and terminate it in terminal, I stuck, following is my code

```
# ~/.bashrc
alias sv='sudo service'


# ex.rb
system "bash -ic 'sv'"
sleep
# in terminal, hit ctrl+c, it stuck
```

But when i try following code, it doesn't stuck

```
system "bash -ic 'source ~/.bashrc; sv'"
sleep
# in terminal, hit ctrl+c, it doesn't stuck
```

I reproduce my question in [screencast](http://youtu.be/wqmk2Z07dts)

my question is why does it stuck?

**update**

[here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B08GAyjqgToLZTBSMHlaTjBYd2c&authuser=0) is my bashrc

Comment: What is the value of `sv` in the second case?  What does ctrl+d do?

Comment: @cdarke As what I say, alias sv="sudo service", I have hit ctrl+d in screencast, nothing happen.

Comment: I believe the issue is that the sudo is prompting for a password but the system call is not in an interactive shell and thus hangs. If you ran your program is root it would probably be ok.

Comment: @Max It can't explain why when i add a 'source ~/.bashrc', everything work well.

Comment: @nwaicaethi Both examples have `source ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: @max sorry, I update my code

Comment: Can you add the contents of your `~/.bashrc` file?

Comment: @Max I upload my bashrc, it's too complex, you can see its ctn in [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B08GAyjqgToLZTBSMHlaTjBYd2c&authuser=0)